# NotSupportedException on UWP Unity build with iText7

Tags: unity-game-engine, pdf, uwp, itext, itext7

I am developing an app for Universal Windows Platform in Unity and I am using iText 7.1.14 to generate a PDF from script. On editor it works fine and gets to export my .pdf file. I don't get any error during the building process. However, I am getting the following exception from a development UWP build:

`NotSupportedException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager::GetSection`

[image: Here the complete console log]

I did several builds by changing the *SDK* and *ScriptingBackend* plugin import settings, but it's still not working. Also, I switched between targeting .NET 4.x and .NET Standard 2.0 APIs without sucess.

I have been researching about the iText library support for UWP but I haven't found clear information about it. At this point, I am not sure if iText 7.1.14 plugins support UWP builds. Some ideas?

Just to be clear, I'd prefer to discard the possibility of using iText before looking for alternative free/paid solutions like Syncfusion, XFinium or so.

Thank you so much!

Comment: well, even if it is an image and there is no link behind it, that would suggest that it [supports UWP](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/media/images/itext-7-and-uwp)

Comment: after further investigations it seems that iText is using Core.NET and therefore it is usable with UWP

Comment: @nka_Zz confirmed, iText 7 is using .NET Core. For a full list of all supported .NET versions, see https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/itext-news-technical-notes/announcing-deprecation-support-net-standard-16

Comment: That image and no link behind is something I'll report to the web team.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thank you for the response! Just to clarify, has iText7 also support to .NET Framework 4.x ? I'm interested on that because I'm using Unity to build my UWP application and I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this exception. Thank you again.

Comment: @nka_Zz Thank you for your fast reply! Checking the [Unity's .NET profile support documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html), I have seen that Unity works only with external plugins compiled against .NET Standard and .NET Framework (about Core, as far as I understand, it's not supported in any case). That's why I'm interested on "matching" the APIs compatibility.

Comment: About the image with no link, I found a possibly [related post](https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/digital-signatures-universal-application-uwp-itext-reblog) on the iText's blog, just if it helps. @AmedeeVanGasse

Comment: @kikoalfaro but if i'm not mixing up anything, it is using .net standard 2.0 and that includes .net core up to version 2.0 and .net framework  up to 4.6.1 and UWP supports .net standard 2.0

Comment: @nka_Zz Yes, definitively the library supports it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

After several tries, the project has built by doing the following steps:

- Removed all the iText7 content of Plugins folder.
- Reimported iText7 with all its .dll dependencies.
- For each library, I have kept one .dll for .NET 4.x and another one for .NET Standard 2.0.
- I have configured the Import settings to make the .NET Standard 2.0 ones work only on the build (excluding Editor)

Then, it have worked on a UWP build with API Compatibility Level .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: It is better if you could mark your answer so that other people who has the same question could refer to this case.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Thank you for the tip! How could I do it? This was my first post, so I'm still learning how the platform works.

Comment: Very easy! Here is a [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you could refer to.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Thank you so much, very appreciated! It should be marked now.

Comment: @kikoalfaro coud you provide a bit more insight on how you did this?
We are currently facing the same issue.

Like how did you get the dll's in 4.x and 2.0?